# Automatically discard old notifications

Tags: notifications, push-notifications

I'm new to the android OS, and have a few devices: Chromebook, android tablet, and android phone running google's standard OS.

I've noticed when I have my phone off all morning and turn it on at lunch time, I get a stream of notifications of all the chat/email/etc that happened while the device was off, even if I engaged with them on my tablet or other devices. An extreme example, I went on vacation for a week, left my tablet off at home. When I came home and turned the tablet on, the OS was unusable while it pulled a week of chat and other app notifications.

My question: is there a setting / configuration on Android to tell it to discard any push notifications it may have gotten while offline but still display any notifications it gets while on?

Comment: Android can't receive or discard push notifications. It's the individual matter of every app you are using.

Comment: Every Google push notification has a maximum life-time defined by the service which creates the push message. As the notification messages are only received by the apps there is usually nothing you can do on app-side. If the service that is sending push notifications has a web-site you may be able to configure the life-time of notification message there if the developer of the service has implement a configuration option for doing so.